# Disable folder drag and drop in Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, drag-and-drop

Is there any way (config / plugin) to disable the drag and drop of folders (not messages) in Thunderbird? I often use this feature accidentally, screwing up my whole mailbox.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this addon.

[Disable DragAndDrop](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/4591)

[image]